# Java intellij multiple line strings

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am currently devving in inttelij for java, being a phpstorm user previously I am used to setting up strings the span multiple lines like this (which I am aware is incorrect Java syntax):

```
@Query("select count(*) from table where
        value= :xxx
        AND value= :xxx2")
```

when it expects to be set up like this:

```
@Query("select count(*) from table where "+
       "value= :xxx "+
       "AND value2 =:xxx2)
```

Is there some kind of string editor plugin I can use on intelliJ, or some kind of code formatting option I can use to make this more or less like phpstorm?

Comment: Not a Java guy at all .. but does **Alt+Enter** while having caret inside such string offers you to edit external fragment? No other ideas.

Comment: The first one is not valid java syntax.

Comment: @LazyOne I get edit JPA QL fragment which looks like it gives me what I want, nice one

Comment: @kan You are correct -- that's PHP kind of syntax (where string literal can contain line breaks and can be spread on multiple lines without need of concatenation).

Comment: On Mac I can put the caret inside the string and use **Cmd+Enter** and it will split the one-liner string and create a string per line which is concatenated with `+`. As @kan has already mentioned, your first version is invalid Java while the second version is valid Java. IntelliJ offers however the ability to wrap a (very) long string at the end of the line (`Preferences/IDE Settings/Editor` and check here `Use soft wraps in editor` and/or `Use soft wraps in console`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can edit a query and maintain its formatting for a Mysql query string by going Alt+Enter -> Inject Language/Reference Mysql then Alt+Enter again -> Edit Mysql fragment on the injected fragment.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is Java, not PHP so the way string literals are represented in source code is defined very strictly by the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

> It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear after the
>   opening " and before the closing matching ".

But all modern IDEs help by breaking the string correctly if you press Enter within a string literal.

(By the way, your query string is wrong, as it reads `select count(*) from table wherevalue=...`)